# show additional row where column value is null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below table structure

```
+-----+------+-----+------------+-------+
| sch | clas | std |    date    | count |
+-----+------+-----+------------+-------+
| A   | a1   | Ax  | 31 nov2018 |     2 |
| A   | a1   | Bo  | 1-Dec-19   |     7 |
| A   | b1   | Ax  | 3-Oct-19   |     3 |
| A   | b1   | Ct  | 2-Dec-10   |     2 |
+-----+------+-----+------------+-------+
```

in which i need to Show a row like below

```
+-----+------+-----+------------+-------+
| sch | clas | std |    date    | count |
+-----+------+-----+------------+-------+
| A   | a1   | Ax  | 31 nov2018 | 2     |
| A   | a1   | Bo  | 1-Dec-19   | 7     |
| A   | a1   | Ct  | null       | null  |
| A   | b1   | Ax  | 3-Oct-19   | 3     |
| A   | b1   | Bo  | null       | null  |
| A   | b1   | Ct  | 2-Dec-10   | 2     |
+-----+------+-----+------------+-------+
```

Column "std" having common values for all the Class ie. Ax,Bo and Ct. 
If those are not available need to SHOW a row with null values for date and count. 
In PLSQL its easily achievable but here i need to do it in SQL or sql server or Postgresql.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Assuming I understand what you're going for, basically you want to cross join all distinct sch/clas/std combinations then left join your original table where there are matches...

Comment: Thanks for reply.  Can you elaborate what you suggested to do.

Comment: Basically do what Tim's answer suggests, except the CTEs would be replaced with `SELECT DISTINCT sch FROM mytable`, `SELECT DISTINCT clas FROM mytable` etc

Comment: Just be curious how easy it is in PLSQL.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate the rows with a `cross join`, then use `left join` to bring in the values.

From what I understand:

```
select t.sch, t.clas, v.std, t.date, t.cnt
from (select distinct sch, clas from t) sc cross join
     (values ('Ax'), ('Bo'), ('Ct')) v(std) left join
     t
     on t.sch = sc.sch and t.clas = sc.clas and t.std = v.std
order by t.sch, t.clas, v.std;
```

Comment: Much appriciated your answers.  Dont want to insert data in the table, just need to show the data as shown in the last table.  Also need to group by with sch, class and order by std as it show Ax, Bo and Ct in sequence.    Like sch A  - Class a1 and then std sequence

Comment: You can just order the rows using `order by`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your table is called Data, then this

- gets a lists of school - classes from the table (c)
- gets a list of std from the table (s)
- cross joins them to get every possible combination
- left joins that to the original data

If you have other tables with the valid school / class/ std data, then it would probably be better to get the data from them, as this won't work for any value that doesn't exist in the Data table at least once.

```
Select cs.sch, cs.cls, cs.std, d.date, d.count
From 
(
   Select c.sch, c.cls, s.std
   From (Select distinct sch, cls from Data) c  --List of school/classes
   Cross Join (select distinct std from Data) s --list of std
) cs  --every possible combination of school/classes and std
left outer join Data D on D.sch = cs.sch and D.cls = cs.cls and D.std = cs.std  --try and join to the original data
```

Comment: With a huge data its taking time so please help me in tuning part.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a calendar table here, to generate the missing data.  Then, left join to your table.

```
WITH sch AS (
    SELECT 'A' AS sch
),
clas AS (
    SELECT 'a1' AS clas UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b1'
),
std AS (
    SELECT 'Ax' AS std UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Bo' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Ct'
)

SELECT
    s.sch,
    c.clas,
    st.std,
    t.date,
    t.count
FROM sch s
CROSS JOIN clas c
CROSS JOIN std st
LEFT JOIN yourTable t
    ON t.sch = s.sch AND t.clas = c.clas AND t.std = st.std
ORDER BY
    s.sch,
    c.clas,
    st.std;
```

Comment: Select cs.sch, cs.cls, cs.std, d.date, d.count
From 
(
   Select c.sch, c.cls, s.std
   From (Select distinct sch, cls from Data) c  --List of school/classes
   Cross Join (select distinct std from Data) s --list of std
) cs  --every possible combination of school/classes and std
left outer join Data D on D.sch = cs.sch and D.cls = cs.cls and D.std = cs.std  --try and join to the original data                                                                                                                 It works perfectly please help with tuning part as data is huge.

Comment: `please help with tuning part as data is huge` ... you should open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

`-- Edited:` If you change your requirement from `INSERT` rows to table to `SHOW` result from table, then you could use this:

```
WITH std_table AS
(
    SELECT 'Ax' AS std UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Bo' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Ct' 
)
, tmp_table AS 
(
    SELECT t.sch, t.clas, s.std 
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT sch, clas FROM table_name) t
    CROSS JOIN std_table s
)
SELECT t.sch, t.clas, t.std, t1.date, t1.count
FROM tmp_table t
LEFT JOIN table_name t1
ON t.sch = t1.sch AND t.clas = t1.clas AND t.std = t1.std
ORDER BY t.sch, t.clas, t.std;
```

`-- End edited`

You could use this, assume your table's name is `table_name`

```
WITH std_table AS
(
    SELECT 'Ax' AS std UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Bo' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Ct' 
)
, tmp_table AS 
(
    SELECT t.sch, t.clas, s.std 
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT sch, clas FROM table_name) t
    CROSS JOIN std_table s
)
INSERT INTO table_name (sch, clas, std)
SELECT t.sch, t.clas, t.std
FROM tmp_table t
LEFT JOIN table_name t1
ON t.sch = t1.sch AND t.clas = t1.clas AND t.std = t1.std
WHERE t1.std IS NULL;
```